# What is the difference between visiting a member vector in class and visit a vector created in another member function?

Tags: c++, class

I was trying to solve Leetcode question [589](https://leetcode.com/problems/n-ary-tree-preorder-traversal/) "N-ary Tree Preorder Traversal".
I have two implementations with same logic as below:
The first one is trying to visit and member vector in class:

```
class sth {
public:
  vector<int> nums;
  vector<int>
  preorder(Node *root) {
    if(!root)
      return nums;
    nums.push_back(root->val);
    for(auto i : root->children)
      preorder(i);
    return nums;
  }
}
```

and the second one is trying to visit an vector that is created in another member function.

```
class sth {
public:
  void
  tracking(Node *root, vector<int> &nums) {
    if(!root)
      return;
    nums.push_back(root->val);
    for(auto i : root->children) {
      tracking(i, nums);
    }
    return;
  }
  vector<int>
  preorder(Node *root) {
    vector<int> nums;
    tracking(root, nums);
    return nums;
  }
}
```

I do not know the difference between these two implementations. They are trying to describe identical logic, however the time and space complexities differ significantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first implementation every `preorder` call returns a vector by value. That means that for every single node you visit you're copying the vector you've built up to that point. Also, since the vector is part of the state of the `sth` object, calling `preorder` a second time will reuse the same vector that already has data in it.

In the second implementation you're only copying the vector a single time when returning it (or not at all as the copy can be [elided](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)). And since there's no outside state, repeated calls to `preorder` will return the same thing.